# How to test the significant of multiply chi square tests

Tags: r, chi-squared-test, combining-p-values

I know that if I have a model from which I have a very large sample, so that I can create a null distribution. And I also have an experimental sample, I can use the ChiSquare test (or FisherExact test) to reject the hypothesis that the sample originated from the distribution (from the model), as follows:

```
x <- c(89,37,30,28,2)
p <- c(0.40,0.2,0.2,0.15,0.05)
chisq.test(x, p = p)
```

My question is: I have a model that creates two independent null distribution (two large samples from which I can create two null distribution), and I have two samples, each sample is related to a different distribution. I want to test if my model is correct/incorrect. I can test using the Chi-square test above each sample against each distribution, but I am searching how to test both distributions at the same time or something in this line of reasoning?
Assuming this is my data

```
x <- c(89,37,30,28,2)
p <- c(40,20,20,15,5)


x1 <- c(53,57,60,128,9)
p1 <- c(30,12,21,155,15)
p1 <- p1/sum(p1)
```

is there a test that can take into consideration both null hypotesis and samples?

Thank you

Comment: See Fisher's method (e.g. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher's_method)) and other posts with the tag [`[combining-p-values]`](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/combining-p-values)

Comment: I don't see how you could use the Fisher Exact test as a goodness of fit test.

Comment: @Glen_b I follow this video - https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=udyAvvaMjfM assuming I have a very large sample from the model (This is how I create p)

Comment: @Glen_b I've edited my question so it will fit. Please free to edit it if you think you can make it more clear

Answer (score 1):

As @Glen_b stated, you can use the [Fisher's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method) method.

In R, you can use the [metap](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/metap/index.html) package :

`pval = metap::sumlog(c(pval1, pval2))`

If you want to weight your pvalues, you can also use the [Stouffer's](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%27s_method#Relation_to_Stouffer's_Z-score_method) method with the [sumz](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/metap/versions/1.1/topics/sumz) function :

```
#if pval1 is twice as important as pval2
pval = metap::sumz(c(pval1, pval2), c(1,2))
```